# MySQL set value of addional field to auto_increment value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT id`, this table also has a `parent_id` field.  In certain cases, when the insert data is itself a parent and has no parent, I need to set the `parent_id` to the same value as its own id.

Is this possible with a single sql statement, or do I have to do a `LAST_INSERT_ID` and a separate update statement?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you leave it empty? if you have a self-referential relationship  it would basically mean you don't have a parent/parent is self.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do in separated statements.

The tree system usually assumes '0' as root or father of no-father items or father of the first level items, and '0' not exists in database.

I recommend you not to set the same id of the item as parent of this item because... this item is his own father? you really need that?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, though I advise highly against it. The only way this query could work is if you can guarantee that no records will be deleted, and even still I say don't use it. But if you must...

```
INSERT INTO `table` (field1, field2, parent_id)
VALUES('data1', 'data2', 
            (SELECT id FROM (SELECT max(id) AS id FROM `table`) AS a) + 1
       )
```

Again though, you're better off doing it in 2 queries. Reason being is the way AI works. If the last record is 20 and it gets deleted, the next entry will be 21 but the parent_id will be 20 because it will see the `max(id)` as 19.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. To get the next auto_increment value for your table you can do:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_name='table_name' 
AND table_schema='schema_name';
```

Don't use `MAX`, because if you remove the last row from table and calculate max, it will not give you the next auto_increment value.